# How do I achieve this look for the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, shaders, ambient-occlusion

How do you get your objects to look like that? is it an addon/plugin/shader/a setting you change?

Tried searching for an ambient occlusion shader or something but came up with nothing.

I was watching this [Blender tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6x2e1Jxtf0k&t=155s) and the guy had it set up like this and I really want to get it too.

He just added a cube and it automatically appeared like this.

[image: screenshot]**

Comment: Have you tried the options in the Viewport Shading panel? Like Cavity for example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this using the solid view settings. They can be accessed in the dropdown menu in the top right corner of your screen, as shown in the picture. Copying the settings I use gets it pretty similar to the picture you posted.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!